# re.findall Returning Correct Quantity of Matches, But All Empty Strings

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to build a list of literals in a string of PL/FOL formulae, and the relevant piece of code is finding matches, but returning them as blanks.

I've tried `re.escape(formula)`, which did nothing. I also have tried simple variants on the `findall` pattern, but they then generate empty lists.

```py
def clean(formula):
    formula = formula.strip()
    formula = re.sub("\( +", "(", formula)
    formula = re.sub(" +\)", ")", formula)
    formula = re.sub("(?P<b_ops>[&v→↔])", " " + "\g<b_ops>" + " ", formula)
    formula = re.sub("[ ]+", " ", formula)
    # Make an inventory of literals for the original formula.
    orig_lit_inv = re.findall("[~]*[A-Z]([a-u]|[w-z]){0,}", formula)
    print(orig_lit_inv)


this_WFF = "(P) & ~(~(Q → (R & ~S)))"
clean(formula=this_WFF)
```

When I print the result, I get `['', '', '', '']`. In other words, it's finding the matches, but is returning blank strings as those matches, when it should at least return matches of `[A-Z]`. With `this_WFF` as the parameter, `clean(formula)` should print `['P', 'Q', 'R', '~S']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [`re.findall`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

> If one or more capturing groups are present in the pattern, return
>       a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
>       has more than one group.

Your regex contains one capturing group, so `findall` will never return anything for the `[A-Z]` part of the regex. change `([a-u]|[w-z])` to `(?:[a-u]|[w-z])` to  see the difference:

```
>>> this_WFF = "(P) & ~(~(Q → (R & ~S)))"
>>> def clean(formula):
...     formula = formula.strip()
...     formula = re.sub("\( +", "(", formula)
...     formula = re.sub(" +\)", ")", formula)
...     formula = re.sub("(?P<b_ops>[&v→↔])", " " + "\g<b_ops>" + " ", formula)
...     formula = re.sub("[ ]+", " ", formula)
...     # Make an inventory of literals for the original formula.
...     orig_lit_inv = re.findall("[~]*[A-Z]([a-u]|[w-z]){0,}", formula)
...     print(orig_lit_inv)
... 
>>> clean(this_WFF)
['', '', '', '']
>>> def clean(formula):
...     formula = formula.strip()
...     formula = re.sub("\( +", "(", formula)
...     formula = re.sub(" +\)", ")", formula)
...     formula = re.sub("(?P<b_ops>[&v→↔])", " " + "\g<b_ops>" + " ", formula)
...     formula = re.sub("[ ]+", " ", formula)
...     # Make an inventory of literals for the original formula
...     orig_lit_inv = re.findall("[~]*[A-Z](?:[a-u]|[w-z]){0,}", formula)
...     print(orig_lit_inv)
... 
>>> clean(this_WFF)
['P', 'Q', 'R', '~S']
```

Since now the regex contains no capturing group `findall` simply returns the content of "group 0" (i.e. the whole match) in the result.